# If ChaCha20 is being used just as a CSPRNG, is nonce needed?

Tags: random-number-generator, nonce, chacha

I'm planning to use ChaCha20 just as a CSPRNG. Key is random (taken from strong initial entropy source) and will be constantly replaced via [DJB's fast key-erasure scheme](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20170723-random.html). What should I use as the nonce? Does it matter? Is it safe to just use zero?

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't matter, as you won't be switching the nonce on a per message basis, just outputting a stream of random data.

However, remember, your key will only produce an output stream valid until the internal counter overflows.

Consider `XChaCha20`.

IETF `ChaCha20` uses a `96-bit` nonce and **32-bit counter**, `XChaCha20` uses a `192-bit` nonce and `64-bit` counter. The `64-bit` counter lets it encrypt `1` `Zettabyte` of data, i.e. output a large random dataset.

Comment: I'm using the original DJB spec for ChaCha that has 64-bit counter and nonce, rather than the IETF's broken version with 32-bit counter and 96-bit nonce, but in any case the counter is unlikely to ever exceed 2 or 3 due to re-keying.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE  Can you please tell me, why IETF ChaCha20 is broken ?

Comment: @Woodstock  Can I encrypt and authenticate 1 Zettabyte of data using XChaCha20- Poly1305 with 192 bit nonce and 64 bit counter ?

Comment: @VivekanandV: 32-bit block counters are largely considered to be a bug/mistake because they compromise security properties if more than 4G blocks are encrypted. DJB intentionally made the counter 64-bit for that reason, and then the IETF spec changed it for inexplicable reasons.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE Thankyou for your reply! How much data can XChaCha20-Poly1305 with 64 bit counter encrypt and authenticate ?

Comment: @VivekanandV: See what Woodstock wrote. But that's really outside the scope of the question here and should be a new question.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE Chacha20  is used by BSD type operating systems, for arc4random() family of functions...